# Showing that in a given set of 7 distinct integers that there must be at least one pair in the set whose sum or difference is a multiple of 10.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Show that, given any set of seven distinct integers, there must be at least one pair in the set whose sum
or difference is a multiple of 10.

I've been thinking a lot on how to show that this is true, but I've not managed to come up with anything yet. If anyone could offer their viewpoint I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Think modulo $10$

Comment: Hi @cosmo5 I did have a look at the post you suggested before but I'm unsure how the squares of the numbers being congruent helps me here. Sorry

Comment: Observe that $x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)(x  - y)$.

Comment: @IdkWhyIdk, is my answer helpful?

Comment: I think so, since the 7th would be identical can I just say that because of the pigeonhole principle that adding a 7th means it would guarantee  that the sum or difference of 2 of them would be a multiple of 10.

Comment: Yes. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $10$, numbers are $0, (1,-1), (2,-2), (3,-3), (4,-4), 5$.

If six numbers are all distinct modulo $10$

- seventh is either identical to one of previous in which case difference is divisible by $10$.
- seventh is negative to one of previous, then sum is divisible by $10$.